# Select distinct instances substring from a column

Tags: sql, substring, distinct, sql-like

I have a column containing substring variations of 'SN'. I just want to see the distinct variations of this plus 1 character on either side, not the whole field.

| Field1 | SYMBOL |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | safsdafsadfs aSN fsadfsadf |
| 2 | sadfsdafb_SN0 sdfsadfsadf |
| 3 | adsfsjSN |
| 4 | 23 SN dfe |

So I'd want to see; aSN, _SN0, jSN, SN .
The below returns each field.

```
SELECT DISTINCT SYMBOL
FROM table
WHERE SYMBOL LIKE '%SN%'
```

I checked [SQL: selecting distinct substring from a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611099/sql-selecting-distinct-substring-from-a-field) and some others but no luck. Any help appreciated. This is using Netezza DB.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a _set quantifier_, and works on the whole selected rows. Skip the extra parentheses and simply write `SELECT DISTINCT SYMBOL
FROM table WHERE SYMBOL LIKE '%SN%'`, to make code clearer.

Comment: Can you paste the code you have tried with no luck, please?

Comment: I have, I don't know where to go from here. Substring_index does not seem to be useful nor substring even.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED (I haven't read that you are using Netezza):

Maybe the query you are looking for is (not tested):

```
SELECT DISTINCT substr(symbol, strpos(symbol, 'SN')-1 , 3)
```

BUT... You will have a problem if the Symbol field has another "SN" before. For example "snafsdafsadfs aSN fsadfsadf". You will have problems because you cannot know which one is the correct SN.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for your help but this doesn't seem to work in Netezza. I guess I need to use substr('SN',-1,4) instead. Then select the distincts.

Comment: @AmyRose I did not advise your were using Netezza, sorry. I have updated it.